# Could a nonhuman-Xenomorph offspring be queen?

Tags: alien-franchise

After the queen dies in the "Alien vs Predator" game, Specimen 6 becomes the new queen because she is the strongest living female left in the area, if I am correct. My question is: what if the only female left was a Predator-Xenomorph or an animal-Xenomorph, like in Alien<sup>3</sup>? Would it produce different facehuggers, or just manage to be even more frightening?

Comment: AVP isn't canon. Aliens 3 isn't canon. In fact, no movies were made after Aliens.

Comment: @JohnO - The Aliens3, Alien: Resurrection and Prometheus aren't cannon?

Comment: @SteB also *there is no star wars prequels* and *they never made [any sequel to the Matrix](http://xkcd.com/566/)*

Comment: @SteB Aliens3 is canon and  Prometheus is going to be conected to aliens . AVP & AVP is not canon.

Comment: After _Aliens_, nobody ever made a sequel to the series. It's puzzling, really. Woah, maybe... maybe in some alternative universe someone decided to make a series of horrible, completely-missing-the-point sequels! With ridiculous crossovers, too! Thank god it didn't happen in _this_ universe.

Comment: Presumably aliens developed into queens before they ever encountered humans, so I don’t see why not.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where did the Alien Queen come from?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/17481/where-did-the-alien-queen-come-from)

Comment: I don't see how that's a duplicate.  We don't need to speculate on types of facehuggers.  The fact that the crew of the Nostromo discovered alien eggs on LV-426, before any humans had previously met an alien, means that it must be possible for queens to arise without humans involved.  Very simple.

Answer (score 1):

I think that non-human Xenomorph queens would be able to produce more dangerous offspring, especially in the case of a PredAlien.

I'm taking into account their more powerful nature.  The hybrid from AVPR manged to wipe out a whole Predator hunting party, not to mention multiple humans before it got killed.

So I think the answer is yes, and they'd make even more deadly critters than human-based Xenomorph spawn.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the particular brand of canon you subscribe to, the Xenomorphs have absolutely zero bias towards reproducing using humans over other species, they're simply the most common prey of the right mass seen in the stories (other creatures used include Cows, Dogs, Yaut'ja and a hilariously wide menagerie in the comics)

So given that pure-strain Xenomorphs are not specifically born of humans, I'd say that there's no reason you couldn't get a Queen from another species.

I'd also expect that since the strains we see are all human-born, including their queen, we'd likely see a different variety of xenomorph queen into the bargain.

Comment: What would a "pure strain" xenomorph even be? The facehugger? The weird octopus creature from Prometheus? The tiny worm thing in Prometheus?

Comment: I would assume that pure-strain would entail the result of the creatures infesting their natural prey. New Canon with Prometheus makes it pretty clear that their natural prey is in fact humans. so arguably "pure strain" are the ones we see in Alien/Aliens. But in old-canon it was always implied that they weren't, which I rather think holds a bit more mystery. Of course, you can still reconcile the canons by simply suggesting that Xenomorphs are an inevitable result of the Black Goo and all the tampering in Prometheus and its sequel simply accelerated that process rather than make anything new

Answer (score 0):

Based on one of the video games, Alien vs Predator: Extinction, in order to make a queen, a special face hugger is laid. That face hugger will make a pure-bred Praetorian regardless of what the host was. If the queen dies, one of the praetorians will take her place.

If this is canonical or just made sense for this game is up for debate.